# Reliable way of ordering mulitple std::void_t partial specializations for type traits

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, sfinae, void-t

I want to classify the "level of feature support" for a type.
The type can contain aliases `red` and `blue`. It can contain just one, both , or neither, and I want to classify each of these cases with an `enum class`:

```cpp
enum class holder_type {
    none,
    red,
    blue,
    both
};
```

This is a use-case for the "member detector idiom", and I've tried to implement it using `std::void_t`:

```cpp
// primary template
template <class T, class = void, class = void>
struct holder_type_of
    : std::integral_constant<holder_type, holder_type::none> {};

// substitution failure if no alias T::red exists
template <class T, class Void>
struct holder_type_of<T, std::void_t<typename T::red>, Void>
    : std::integral_constant<holder_type, holder_type::red> {};

// substitution failure if no alias T::blue exists
template <class T, class Void>
struct holder_type_of<T, std::void_t<typename T::blue>, Void>
    : std::integral_constant<holder_type, holder_type::blue> {};

// substitution failure if one of the aliases doesn't exist
template <class T>
struct holder_type_of<T, std::void_t<typename T::blue>, std::void_t<typename T::red>>
    : std::integral_constant<holder_type, holder_type::both> {};
```

However, the first and second partial specialization are redefinitions of each other. The following assertions fail to compile with clang, but succeed with GCC (as wanted).

```cpp
static_assert(holder_type_of<red_holder>::value == holder_type::red);
static_assert(holder_type_of<blue_holder>::value == holder_type::blue);
```

```
<source>:36:8: error: redefinition of 'holder_type_of<T, std::void_t<typename T::blue>, Void>'
struct holder_type_of<T, std::void_t<typename T::blue>, Void>
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:32:8: note: previous definition is here
struct holder_type_of<T, std::void_t<typename T::red>, Void>
       ^
```

*See [live code on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/MjGzWs3dT)*

How do I get my code to compile on all compilers, with all assertions passing? Also, is clang wrong here, and my code should actually work according to the standard?

---

*Note: The example is intentionally artificial, but could could be used in practice for things like classifying iterators as random-access/forward/etc. I've run into this issue when trying to detect members of a trait type that the user can specialize themselves.*

Comment: `template <typename ...> using void_t = void` will always result in `void`, hense (I think)) the redifinition error. You give 2 specializations for `<T, void>` which are virtually the same

Comment: Isn't the problem that `void_t<anything>` is just `void`? So you get `<T, void, void>` everywhere.

Comment: @BoP yes, that's the point. But some are more specialized. I don't understand why the `T::red`-only and `T::blue`-only ones are redefinitions of each other for `T = red_holder`. One of them shouldn't even exist due to substitution failure. I'm starting to suspect that GCC is right here. Or maybe they can't be redefinitions regardless of substitution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like [CWG1980](https://wg21.link/CWG1980) (`std::void_t<typename T::red>` and `std::void_t<typename T::blue>` are deemed "equivalent" since they are both `void`, so they are redefinitions, but they are not functionally equivalent since they can be distinguished by substitution failure).

And even if you were to fix it by making it a dependent `void`, like:

```cpp
template<typename...> struct dependent_void { using type = void; };
template<typename... T> using dependent_void_t = typename dependent_void<T...>::type;
```

It would make these two partial specializations:

```cpp
template <class T, class Void>
struct holder_type_of<T, dependent_void_t<typename T::red>, Void>
    : std::integral_constant<holder_type, holder_type::red> {};
template <class T>
struct holder_type_of<T, dependent_void_t<typename T::blue>, dependent_void_t<typename T::red>>
    : std::integral_constant<holder_type, holder_type::both> {};
```

ambiguous since the middle arguments `dependent_void_t<typename T::red>` and `dependent_void_t<typename T::blue>` are unrelated and not better one way or the other.

... So you can flip the red one's arguments so the last argument is the same and the `dependent_void_t<typename T::blue>` is better than just `Void`. You can even go back to `std::void_t`, as you aren't comparing multiple `std::void_t`s with different template arguments anymore:

```cpp
template <class T, class Void>
struct holder_type_of<T, Void, std::void_t<typename T::red>>
    : std::integral_constant<holder_type, holder_type::red> {};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/s6dPYWeao

This gets unmanageable pretty quickly for multiple conditions

---

"priority" based SFINAE detection is more easily done with function overloads though:

```cpp
// Lowest priority overload
template<typename T>
constexpr holder_type holder_type_of_impl(...) { return holder_type::none; }
template<typename T, std::void_t<typename T::red>* = nullptr>
constexpr holder_type holder_type_of_impl(void*) { return holder_type::red; }
template<typename T, std::void_t<typename T::blue>* = nullptr>
constexpr holder_type holder_type_of_impl(long) { return holder_type::blue; }
template<typename T, std::void_t<typename T::red, typename T::blue>* = nullptr>
constexpr holder_type holder_type_of_impl(int) { return holder_type::both; }
// Highest priority overload

template <class T>
struct holder_type_of
    : std::integral_constant<holder_type, ::holder_type_of_impl<T>(0)> {};

// And if you have more than 4 priorities (probably a sign to break up your checks),
// you can use this handy template

template<unsigned N> struct priority : priority<N-1u> {};
template<> struct priority<0> {};

// Ordered from worst to best match for `f(priority<6>{})`
void f(priority<0>);
void f(priority<1>);
void f(priority<2>);
void f(priority<3>);
void f(priority<4>);
void f(priority<5>);
void f(priority<6>);
```

Comment: How far you can scale these priority-based overloads? Is there an indefinite reliable chain of conversions that you can use? In this example, there are only 4 overloads, and the rules for overload resolution are still somewhat intuitive here, but how would you do it for 5 or 6?

Comment: @JanSchultke I've rarely had to have more than 4 (especially for C++17 code, where you might be able to use an `if constexpr` chain instead) but I've added a solution that works for arbitrarily large overload sets

Comment: I would use `priority<N>` even with `N < 4`: relying on priority of int/long/pointer/C-ellipsis is error prone.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is caused by several specializations of `<T, void_t<>>`, which are evaluated to `<T, void>`, hence the redifinition error.
In order to circumvent this problem, you need some disambiguation for each specialization. Basically, I see no way of escaping writing the specializations for `has_type`.

However, life can be made easier by using tags.
Here's an example of a convenient API that reflects the usage in your artificial example:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct S {};

struct empty {};

struct red_holder {
    using red = S;
};

struct blue_holder {
    using blue = S;
};

struct both_holder {
    using red = S;
    using blue = S;
};

enum /*class*/ holder_type {
    none = 0,
    red = 1,
    blue = 2,
    both = 3
};

namespace tag 
{
    struct red_t {} constexpr red{};
    struct blue_t{} constexpr blue{};
}

template <typename Tag, typename T, typename = void>
struct _has : std::integral_constant<holder_type, holder_type::none>{};

template <typename T>
struct _has<tag::red_t, T, std::void_t<typename T::red>> 
    : std::integral_constant<holder_type, holder_type::red> {};

template <typename T>
struct _has<tag::blue_t, T, std::void_t<typename T::blue>> 
    : std::integral_constant<holder_type, holder_type::blue> {};

template <typename T, typename ... Tags>
constexpr holder_type has(Tags... tags) noexcept {
    const auto flags = (_has<Tags, T>{} | ...);
    return static_cast<holder_type>(flags);
}

template <typename T>
constexpr holder_type has() noexcept {
    return holder_type::none;
}


static_assert(has<empty>() == holder_type::none);
static_assert(has<red_holder>(tag::red) == holder_type::red);
static_assert(has<blue_holder>(tag::blue) == holder_type::blue);

static_assert(has<both_holder>(tag::red) == holder_type::red);
static_assert(has<both_holder>(tag::blue) == holder_type::blue);
static_assert(has<both_holder>(tag::blue, tag::red) == holder_type::both);
```

https://godbolt.org/z/qPax11GYf

Since (it seems to me) you need to have type->value mappings, I suggest using flags.

---

Using tags reduces the necessary boilerplate. Basically for each member detection you have to write 2 class templates (basic "false" + specialization).
By using tags, you now have to write only a specialization. But until we have a reflection support, you **have** to write it.

Comment: If `has` is already taking the traits you're testing for as function parameters, what's the point of still returning the `holder_type`? In this case, you could just `static_assert(has<red_holder>(tag::red))`

Comment: @JanSchultke good luck specilaizing `has<>` for several types. `has<red, blue>` is not the same as `has<blue, red>`, but should yield the same result: `both`. Also, it is impossible to "sort" the types in a template list.  Hence using bit flags here helps a  lot to simplify the usage for your artificial example.

Comment: Your solution just seems a bit over-engineered. If you're going to test whether a type `T` *has a property*, why not make that function return `bool`? You can simplify it like: https://godbolt.org/z/1oYPnx54K and achieve the same effect.

Comment: @JanSchultke I have implied that your goal is to map to a particular `enum` value, so I based my code on your example.

Comment: That is the original goal, but it's not the goal *at all cost*. If my goal was to classify an `int` as `positive` and `negative` and you made a solution with functions `is_positive` and `is_negative`, it would still make sense for those two functions to return a `bool` instead of forcefully fitting them to the solution, in a way that doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers, the problem is that in:

```cpp
template <class T, class Void>
struct holder_type_of<T, std::void_t<typename T::red>, Void>
    : std::integral_constant<holder_type, holder_type::red> {};

// substitution failure if no alias T::blue exists
template <class T, class Void>
struct holder_type_of<T, std::void_t<typename T::blue>, Void>
```

These two partial specializations are the same type. It's possible to solve this by swapping `Void` and `std::void_t` around in one of them, but this doesn't  scale well to larger quantities of partial specializations, because we may need one extra template parameter for each.

A technique which is commonly used in libstdc++ is to add an `int Bullet` template parameter which is used for ordering the partial specializations:

```cpp
// primary template, start at <Bullet = 0> and inherit from <Bullet + 1>
template <class T, int Bullet = 0, class Void = void>
struct holder_type_of : holder_type_of<T, Bullet + 1, Void> {};

// first attempt for <Bullet = 0>
// fall back onto <Bullet = 1> if substitution fails
template <class T>
struct holder_type_of<T, 0, std::void_t<typename T::blue, typename T::red>>
    : std::integral_constant<holder_type, holder_type::both> {};

// Bullet = 1, fall back to Bullet = 2
template <class T>
struct holder_type_of<T, 1, std::void_t<typename T::red>>
    : std::integral_constant<holder_type, holder_type::red> {};

// Bullet = 2, fall back to Bullet = 3
template <class T>
struct holder_type_of<T, 2, std::void_t<typename T::blue>>
    : std::integral_constant<holder_type, holder_type::blue> {};

// Bullet = 3, substitution always succeeds, so we have a fallback case
template <class T>
struct holder_type_of<T, 3, void>
    : std::integral_constant<holder_type, holder_type::none> {};
```

*See [live example at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/5EG5M74fb)*